# numpy.genfromtxt produces array of what looks like tuples, not a 2D array—why?

Tags: python, import, numpy, genfromtxt

I'm running `genfromtxt` like below:

```
date_conv = lambda x: str(x).replace(":", "/")
time_conv = lambda x: str(x)

a = np.genfromtxt(input.txt, delimiter=',', skip_header=4,
      usecols=[0, 1] + radii_indices, converters={0: date_conv, 1: time_conv})
```

Where `input.txt` is from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1958483).

When I look at the results, it is a 1D array not a 2D array:

```
>>> np.shape(a)
(918,)
```

It seems to be an array of tuples instead:

```
>>> a[0]
('06/03/2006', '08:27:23', 6.4e-05, 0.000336, 0.001168, 0.002716, 0.004274, 0.004658, 0.003756, 0.002697, 0.002257, 0.002566, 0.003522, 0.004471, 0.00492, 0.005602, 0.006956, 0.008442, 0.008784, 0.006976, 0.003917, 0.001494, 0.000379, 6.4e-05)
```

If I remove the converters specification from the `genfromtxt` call it works fine and produces a 2D array:

```
>>> np.shape(a)
(918, 24)
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

What is returned is called a **structured ndarray**, see e.g. here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html. This is because your data is not homogeneous, i.e. not all elements have the same type: the data contains both strings (the first two columns) and floats. Numpy arrays have to be homogeneous (see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/whatisnumpy.html) for an explanation).

The structured array 'solves' this constraint of homogeneity by using tuples for each record or row, that's the reason the returned array is 1D: one series of tuples, but each tuple (row) consists of several fields, so you can regard it as rows and columns. The different columns are accessible as `a['nameofcolumn']` e.g. `a['Julian_Day']`.

The reason that it returns a 2D array when removing the converters for the first two columns is that in that case, `genfromtxt` regards all data of the same type, and a normal ndarray is returned (the default type is float, but you can specify this with the `dtype` argument).

**EDIT**: If you want to make use of the column names, you can use the `names` argument (and set the `skip_header` at only three):

```
a2 = np.genfromtxt("input.txt", delimiter=',', skip_header=3, names = True, dtype = None,
                  usecols=[0, 1] + radii_indices, converters={0: date_conv, 1: time_conv})
```

the you can do e.g.:

```
>>> a2['Dateddmmyyyy']
array(['06/03/2006', '06/03/2006', '18/03/2006', '19/03/2006',
       '19/03/2006', '19/03/2006', '19/03/2006', '19/03/2006',
       '19/03/2006', '19/03/2006'], 
      dtype='|S10')
```