# 1-D to 2-D array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1-D array in numpy whose shape is (761,) and each entry is a 10 tuple whose elements I can't access independently.  The dtype is

array1.dtype

```
dtype([('Name', '|S58'), ('Category', '|S32'), ('HQLocation', '|S34'),
       ('YearFounded', '<i8'), ('Latitude', '<f8'), ('Longitude', '<f8'), 
       ('TotalFundingAmount', '<i8'), ('LastFundingAmount', '<i8'), 
       ('Investors', '<i8'), ('NGrams', '|S98')])
```

An example row is array1[578]

```
('"FoxyP2, Inc."', 'Education', '"Cuajimalpa, Mexico"', 2006, 19.3547, 
 -99.3001, 55317213, 42999977, 3, 
 'english;learning;reinvent;experience;english learning')
```

I'm trying to make this into a 2-D array whose shape is (761,10) while keeping the column names and data types.

Comment: I think this question may be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534408/numpy-genfromtxt-produces-array-of-what-looks-like-tuples-not-a-2d-arraywhy

Answer (score 2):

It's just impossible with your input, as the different columns don't have the same type: some of them are strings, some are floats, some integers.

NumPy arrays are homogeneous, meaning that **all** entries must have the same data type. This data type can be simple (`int`, `float`, ...) or complicated (like a tuple whose first element is a `"|S58"`, whose fourth is a `int`, whose fifth is a `float`...), but in any case, all the entries have the same type. You can get more information in the documentation, [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/user/basics.types.html) and [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/user/basics.rec.html#structured-arrays).

But why do you need a 2D array? You can access and manipulate each column independently with indexing (eg, `your_array[YearFounded]` will return your fourth column)...

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of data type is "|S58"?