# How do I load heterogeneous data (np.genfromtxt) as a 2D array?

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I learn from [numpy.genfromtxt produces array of what looks like tuples, not a 2D array—why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534408/numpy-genfromtxt-produces-array-of-what-looks-like-tuples-not-a-2d-array-why) that `numpy.genfromtxt` returns a *structured* ndarray if the data is not homogeneous. **How do I load heterogeneous data as a 2D array?**

For instance, a text file whose contents are: (all items except the header are `int`)

```
# c1    c2  c3  c4  c5
3   4   8   6   8
10  7   6   7   10
5   10  2   1   3
7   6   5   3   6
5   8   5   2   7
1   2   2   10  8
10  5   9   3   8
5   2   4   4   2
```

Load data using `np.genfromtxt`,

```
# load data from a text file
table = np.genfromtxt('table.dat', dtype=int, delimiter='\t', names=True, filling_values=0)
print(table.shape)
print(table)

# output
(8,)
[(3, 4, 8, 6, 8) (10, 7, 6, 7, 10) (5, 10, 2, 1, 3) (7, 6, 5, 3, 6)
 (5, 8, 5, 2, 7) (1, 2, 2, 10, 8) (10, 5, 9, 3, 8) (5, 2, 4, 4, 2)]

# expecting result
(8, 5)
[[ 7  2  4  9  2]
 [ 5  8  1  6  4]
 [ 6  3  1  4 10]
 [10 10  6  5  5]
 [10  4  7  7  1]
 [ 1  9  8  6  2]
 [ 3  2  3  4  4]
 [ 7  5  9 10  6]]
```

PS: I wanna keep `header = table.dtype.names` for other purpose.

Comment: Any particular reason the data in the expected result has no resemblance to the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case use pandas and then converting pandas dataframe to numpy matrix would be easier.

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.read_csv('table.dat', sep='\t')
type(foo)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
bar = foo.as_matrix()
array([[10,  7,  6,  7, 10],
       [ 5, 10,  2,  1,  3],
       [ 7,  6,  5,  3,  6],
       [ 5,  8,  5,  2,  7],
       [ 1,  2,  2, 10,  8],
       [10,  5,  9,  3,  8],
       [ 5,  2,  4,  4,  2]])
bar.shape
(7,5)
```

Comment: I missed copying the first line of table.dat file

Comment: How about `table = table.view(int, len(table.dtype.names))`?

Comment: I think you still have tuple issue. view() is just a view. It does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work with:

```
import numpy as np

table = np.genfromtxt('table.dat',
                      dtype=None,
                      skip_header=1)
```

Here's why it works:

- You should consecutive whitespace as the delimiter (the default) not tabs (unless the snippet you posted has lost formatting).
- You should let NumPy infer the `dtype`, rather than using the default `float`.
- To get the desired output in your question you want to simply skip the header column rather than get the function to create a structured `dtype`.

Check out the docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html for more details.

I agree a Pandas DataFrame may be more appropriate if you are essentially reading in a csv file.

Comment: Thx, but at the cost of missing the first row, `header = table.dtype.names` (I use it for other purpose)

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks homogeneous - all int except for the header.  But by saying `header=True` you force it to load it as a structured array.  Look at the `dtype`.

Try `skip_header=1` (check the syntax).  Omit `names` (or make it false).

In other words you want to load integers, ignoring the header line.

The tab delimiter appears to be working ok.

I see from a comment that you have discovered the `view` method of converting a structured array.  That gives you both header names and a 2d view.