# Read textfile into numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I'm trying to load a [textfile](http://practicalcryptography.com/media/cryptanalysis/files/english_trigrams.txt.zip) into a numpy array.

The structure is the following:

```
THE 77534223
AND 30997177
ING 30679488
ENT 17902107
ION 17769261
HER 15277018
FOR 14686159
THA 14222073
NTH 14115952
[...]
```

But I fail using

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt("english_trigrams.txt", dtype=(str,int), delimiter=' ')                                                   
print(data)

[['TH' '77']
 ['AN' '30']
 ['IN' '30']
 ..., 
 ['JX' '1']
 ['JQ' '1']
 ['JQ' '1']]
```

I want an (x,2) array with dtype `str` in the first column and dtype `int` in the second.

**Thanks a lot!**

---

**P.s.:**

- Python 3.6.1
- NumPy 1.13.0

Comment: maybe try np.loadtxt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use numpy.genfromtxt when first column is string and the remaining columns are numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319969/how-to-use-numpy-genfromtxt-when-first-column-is-string-and-the-remaining-column)

Comment: `np.loadtxt("english_trigrams.txt", dtype=[('f0', '|S3'),('f1', '<i8')])`

Comment: just out of curiosity, but do you intend to change `77534223` frome the file to `77` ?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters: I've read this post but I did not get anywhere.
@MaximilianPeters: This gives me a `dim (17556,)` array.
@MarvinTaschenberger: No, I did not change anything. I need to stick with `77534223` :-)

Comment: @smoneck: see here for an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534408/numpy-genfromtxt-produces-array-of-what-looks-like-tuples-not-a-2d-array-why

Comment: *"I want an (x,2) array with dtype str in the first column and dtype int in the second."*  That is not possible with numpy.  What you *can* get is a one-dimensional structured array, using the approach suggested by @MaximilianPeters.

Answer (score 0):

Various ways of loading this text

```
In [470]: txt=b"""THE 77534223
     ...: AND 30997177
     ...: ING 30679488
     ...: ENT 17902107
     ...: ION 17769261
     ...: HER 15277018
     ...: FOR 14686159
     ...: THA 14222073
     ...: NTH 14115952"""
```

Let `genfromtxt` deduce the correct column dtype

```
In [471]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype=None)
In [472]: data
Out[472]: 
array([(b'THE', 77534223), (b'AND', 30997177), (b'ING', 30679488),
       (b'ENT', 17902107), (b'ION', 17769261), (b'HER', 15277018),
       (b'FOR', 14686159), (b'THA', 14222073), (b'NTH', 14115952)],
      dtype=[('f0', 'S3'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

Not the right dtype specification; like yours but with just 1 char per element.

```
In [473]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype=(str, int))
In [474]: data
Out[474]: 
array([['T', '7'],
       ['A', '3'],
       ['I', '3'],
       ['E', '1'],
       ['I', '1'],
       ['H', '1'],
       ['F', '1'],
       ['T', '1'],
       ['N', '1']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

A little better - but the strings are too short

```
In [475]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype='str,int')
In [476]: data
Out[476]: 
array([('', 77534223), ('', 30997177), ('', 30679488), ('', 17902107),
       ('', 17769261), ('', 15277018), ('', 14686159), ('', 14222073),
       ('', 14115952)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

Similar to the `dtype=None` case

```
In [477]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype='U10,int')
In [478]: data
Out[478]: 
array([('THE', 77534223), ('AND', 30997177), ('ING', 30679488),
       ('ENT', 17902107), ('ION', 17769261), ('HER', 15277018),
       ('FOR', 14686159), ('THA', 14222073), ('NTH', 14115952)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U10'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```