# numpy.genfromtxt , are uneven spaces between columns causing dtype errors?

Tags: arrays, numpy, python-import, delimiter, genfromtxt

The data I'm working with can be found at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/sarahsdonohoe/67c0bdb7dddba57e6c1f4bc4f265159f),

And looks like:

```
07-11-2018 18:34:35 -2.001   5571.036 -1.987
07-11-2018 18:34:50 -1.999   5570.916 -1.988
```

[image of code and output in Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLZnu.png)

**When calling**

```
TB_CAL_array = np.genfromtxt('calbath_data/TB118192.TXT',
                            skip_header = 10,
                            dtype = ([("date", "<U10"), ("time","<U8"), ("bathtemp", "<f8"), 
                                    ("SBEfreq", "<f8"), ("SBEtemp", "<f8")])

                               )
```

**Output of array is:**

```
array([('07-11-2018', '18:34:35', -2.001e+00, 5571.036, -1.987),
   ('07-11-2018', '18:34:50', -1.999e+00, 5570.916, -1.988),
```

The data is output as a structured ndarray of tuples and is a non-homogenous array because it contains both strings and floats. [numpy.genfromtxt produces array of what looks like tuples, not a 2D array—why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534408/numpy-genfromtxt-produces-array-of-what-looks-like-tuples-not-a-2d-array-why)

NOTE: The third column of data output  has been treated as something other than the dtype specified.

The output should be `-2.001` but instead it is `-2.001e+00`

NOTE: Notice that the fifth column has the same input format and dtype designation, however no data transformation occurred there during the genfromtxt function...

*The only difference I can find between "bathtemp" and "SBEtemp" is that there are two extra blank spaces after the "bathtemp" column...*

However based on the numpy.genfromtxt IO [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) this shouldn't matter because consecutive whitespace should automatically be treated as a delimiter.:

delimiter : str, int, or sequence, optional
The string used to separate values. By default, any consecutive whitespaces act as delimiter. An integer or sequence of integers can also be provided as width(s) of each field.

**Is the extra whitespace after the "bathtemp" column causing the error? If so how do I work around it?**

Comment: 3rd column is a valid float - scientific notation.

Comment: I don't see any errors.  You got an array that matches the dtype.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59275231/pandas-suppress-scientific-notation - on pandas and numpy scientific notation controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your sample:

```
In [136]: txt="""07-11-2018 18:34:35 -2.001   5571.036 -1.987 
     ...: 07-11-2018 18:34:50 -1.999   5570.916 -1.988"""                       
In [137]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), dtype=None, encoding=None)            
Out[137]: 
array([('07-11-2018', '18:34:35', -2.001, 5571.036, -1.987),
       ('07-11-2018', '18:34:50', -1.999, 5570.916, -1.988)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U10'), ('f1', '<U8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8')])
```

and with your dtype:

```
In [139]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), dtype= ([("date", "<U10"), ("time","<U
     ...: 8"), ("bathtemp", "<f8"),  
     ...:                                     ("SBEfreq", "<f8"), ("SBEtemp", "<
     ...: f8")]) 
     ...: , encoding=None)                                                      
Out[139]: 
array([('07-11-2018', '18:34:35', -2.001, 5571.036, -1.987),
       ('07-11-2018', '18:34:50', -1.999, 5570.916, -1.988)],
      dtype=[('date', '<U10'), ('time', '<U8'), ('bathtemp', '<f8'), ('SBEfreq', '<f8'), ('SBEtemp', '<f8')])
```

Values like `-2.001e+00` are the same as `-2.001`.  `numpy` chooses to use scientific notation when the range of values is wide enough, or some values are too small to show well otherwise.

For example, if I change one of the values to something much smaller:

```
In [140]: data = _                                                              
In [141]: data['bathtemp']                                                      
Out[141]: array([-2.001, -1.999])
In [142]: data['bathtemp'][1] *= 0.001                                          
In [143]: data['bathtemp']                                                      
Out[143]: array([-2.001e+00, -1.999e-03])
```

The `-2.001` is unchanged (except display style).

My guess is that some of the `bathtemp` values (that you don't show) are much closer to zero.

Comment: Thank you, that explanation makes a lot of sense! I do have values at 0.000 in the third column. Strange that numpy automatically uses scientific notation and pandas does not...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the output I was looking for by switching to pd.read_csv because of the skipinitialspace=True optional input (see here for [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)):

skipinitialspace : bool, default False
Skip spaces after delimiter.

**Input**

```
colnames = ['date', 'time', 'bathtemp', 'SBEfreq', 'SBEtemp']
TB_CAL   = pd.read_csv("calbath_data/TB118192.CAL", header=None, skiprows=10, delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=True, names=colnames )
```

**Output**

```
    date    time    bathtemp    SBEfreq SBEtemp
0   07-11-2018  18:34:35    -2.001  5571.036    -1.987
1   07-11-2018  18:34:50    -1.999  5570.916    -1.988
2   07-11-2018  18:35:06    -1.997  5571.058    -1.987
```