# pandas: suppress scientific notation?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The [suggested answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-python-pandas-aggregation-results) aren't working for me. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I believe you need to use the ` pd.set_option` method now

Answer (score 2):

Display options pertain to display of pandas objects. `values` returns a numpy array which is formatted independently from pandas. You can use [`np.set_printoptions`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) here:

```
s = pd.Series([1.2345678])

print(s)
#0    1.234568
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format
print(s)
#0   1.23

print(s.values)
#[1.2345678]
pd.np.set_printoptions(2)
print(s.values)
#[1.23]
```

To suppress scientific notation you can specify a formatter:

```
s = pd.Series([1.2345678e+14])

pd.np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': lambda x: '{:.3f}'.format(x)})
print(s.values)
#[123456780000000.000]
```